# How to determine the type

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, decryption, encoding

Today I discover a encryption method

Which

0 = 35

1 = 34

2 = 37

3 = 36

4 = 31

5 = 30

6 = 33

7 = 32

8 = 3d

9 = 3c

It's the encode of number 1 to 0 for the method

Can you please help me to find the name of the method?

Comment: If each number is __substituted__ by a fixed other value then it is a [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it is not a vague unanswerable question like so many others. In fact, @Luc has clearly and concisely already answered it.

Comment: It is not on topic here though, so no, it should remain closed.

Comment: Ok, but it wasn't closed as "off topic", it was closed as duplicative.

Answer (score 1):

It's an xor cipher with 0x05 as key.

Looking in the ASCII table, the digit 0 is ASCII code 0x30. In binary, that is `110000`. Your ciphertext result is 0x35, which is `110101` in binary. The difference is that third-to-last and last positions are flipped (1 becomes 0 or 0 becomes 1). This is indicative of an xor key `000101` (put a `1` in the positions that flip). Converting `000101` (or simply `101` since leading zeroes can be removed) back to (hexa)decimal, you get 5.

The shortcut to calculating the xor key given a ciphertext and plaintext byte, is to xor them together: `0x35 ^ 0x30 = 0x05`

To confirm this, we can use any other value from your list:

```
0 0x30 ^ 5 = 0x35
1 0x31 ^ 5 = 0x34
2 0x32 ^ 5 = 0x37
...
9 0x39 ^ 5 = 0x3c
```

An easy way to convert between binary / hexadecimal / decimal is python: `hex(0b110101)` gives `0x35` and `bin(0x35)` gives `0b110101`. Note that the `0b` and `0x` notations are just prefixes to indicate the number system (binary and hexadecimal, respectively).